# React generate <option> tags for a <select> element before render

Tags: reactjs

This is my **SearchForm.js**  class

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
      position: '',
      area: '',
      date: '',
      experience: {
           type: Array,
           default: function () { return [] }
          }  
      }

      this.handlePositionChange = this.handlePositionChange.bind(this);
      this.handlePositionKeyUp = this.handlePositionKeyUp.bind(this);  
      this.handleAreaChange = this.handleAreaChange.bind(this); 

    }


    ...

    render() {
        return ( 
            <form className='form search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label htmlFor="experience">Experience</label>
                    <select className="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.experience}>
                      <option key={this.props.experience.id} value={this.props.experience.name}>
                        {this.props.experience.name}
                    </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm }
```

`experience`  must be multiple array with fields `id` and `name` and I need to get its values from other server before rendering form and generate `<option>` tags for a `<select>` element previously. But I don't know how to make it. I use `axios` to send AJAX request on other inputs changes, so maybe I could use it here on window load or something like that?

Comment: use componentDidMount or componentWillMount events to get your data before rendering

Comment: could you give me an example, please?

Comment: see [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/react-ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `componentDidMount` lifecycle function is where you need to make you API request. `componentDidMount` is called once after the initial render

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
      position: '',
      area: '',
      date: '',
      experience: {
           type: Array,
           default: function () { return [] }
          }  
      }

      this.handlePositionChange = this.handlePositionChange.bind(this);
      this.handlePositionKeyUp = this.handlePositionKeyUp.bind(this);  
      this.handleAreaChange = this.handleAreaChange.bind(this); 

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //API request here
        APICall().then(res => {
           this.setState({data: res});
        })
    }
    ...

    render() {
        //conditional rendering here
        if(!this.state.data) {
            return 'Loading...'
        }
        return ( 
            <form className='form search-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label htmlFor="experience">Experience</label>
                    <select className="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.experience}>
                      <option key={this.props.experience.id} value={this.props.experience.name}>
                        {this.props.experience.name}
                    </option>
                    </select>
                  </div>

            </form>
        )
    }
}

export { SearchForm }
```

Comment: He/she wants the data before rendering is what i understood.

Comment: @illiteratewriter, when you make the API request, you can't get the data before the render always since the request is an async one, the simple solution is to have a call in the componentDidMount and whenever the response is available the data is received by the component and is reflected in the select options. Even if you use componentWillMount or render the data will mostly be available after the render is done

Comment: So can't you do conditional rendering?

Comment: @illiteratewriter The only other way is to call an action in parent and only when the data is available, render the SearchForm with the required props or do conditional rendering of the SearchForm while the data is still unavailable

Comment: options?<SearchForm/>:<div/>

Comment: @illiteratewriter, yes that is what I mentioned in the comment, that is also one way to do it. However you can always conditionally render inside the searchForm. It also depends on where you want to make the API request

Comment: But even simple `componentWillUnmount() {  console.log(1); }` doesn't work

Comment: only when the component unmounts, is componentWillUnmount called